# How to pass information from Table View to Detail View

Tags: ios, objective-c

First, thanks in advance!
Second, I have googled and checked forums for an answer that helps, but couldn't find anything that helped. I know it is an area that is asked a lot.

So I am trying to push information to a Detail view controller from a Table View. The information is on a plist. The tutorial I used to get this code is old and uses xibs. Using storyboards, it throws the error below:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:
```

I know that this is because I do not have a xib file named 'DetailViewController'. I want this (and the information from the plist) to be pushed to my "DetailViewController", which is in my storyboard but I can not find the code required to do so.

Could you please help me with this? What changes do I need to make?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *BibleVerses = [BibleReading objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (!self.detailViewController) {
    self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
}
self.detailViewController.detailItem = BibleVerses;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Why do you use an extra nib, since you're using storyboard anyway? And why don't you use segue which is the most convenient way with the least code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your controller is in storyboard, you can use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *BibleVerses = [BibleReading objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (!self.detailViewController) {
    self.detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
}
self.detailViewController.detailItem = BibleVerses;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Ill select as answer when the timer allows me to!

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *BibleVerses = [BibleReading objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIStoryboard * storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    self.detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewControllerIdentifierName"];

    self.detailViewController.detailItem = BibleVerses;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

hope its helpful